# Finding div height after jQuery replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find and replace a div with the id `left_s` with a div with id=`newdiv`. Also, I need to get the `height` and `width` of the previous div `left_s` and apply it to the new div with id=`newdiv`.

I've got this code, but it's not working:

```
$('#left_s').replaceWith('<div id="newdiv" </div>');
var w = $("#newdiv").width();
$(".left_s").width(w);
```

///////after ".replaceWith" i can't get height and width from div "left_s" and apply it to "newdiv".

Comment: There's a typo in your replaceWith, does that have anything to do with your problem? What isn't working?

Comment: You forgot to close the appended div :P Look closely and also remove the leading spaces :P

Comment: after ".replaceWith" i can't get height and width from div "left_s" and apply it to "newdiv".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("body").append('<div id="newdiv"></div>');
$(".left_s").width($("#newdiv").width());
```

You can fix up the code so it matches your purpose, but the key is appending the element into the DOM. Otherwise, it doesn't have a computed width/height.